# SQLite problem (doesn't update)

Tags: database, sqlite, insert, titanium

I have made an SQLite database file with some testdata in it. When I use it in my application it goes well.

Next I have inserted a new row with data into my table with an SQLite manager. Here's where the problem is. When i run my application now, the new data doesn't appear. It's still all the old data (without the newly inserted one).

Does anyone know why the SQLite file isn't updated (Or maybe it's updated but doesn't show the data)?

#### Update:

I use the SQLite manager in FireFox.
I've inserted it with that manager, and when i query the select * from table it shows the new data.
I use the following command to open my database

```
var db = Titanium.Database.install('../test2.sqlite', 'test');
```

Comment: How do we know? Maybe your query is wrong. Have you dumped the database file (use the SQLite shell and enter `.dump`) to check that the newly inserted data is absent? Maybe you do not run the right query, maybe your app overwrites the database with a backup, there could be thousands of reasons.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing some code. How do you open the file (which options), how do you write the data. Are you sure that you open the correct file? Please do not post your entire code, just the relevant parts.

Comment: Well, I use the SQLite manager in FireFox. I've inserted it with that manager, and when i query the select * from table it shows the new data. I use the following command to open my database "var db = Titanium.Database.install('../test2.sqlite', 'test');"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is typically i think. your database seems to be cached. you should change the name

```
var db = Titanium.Database.install('../test2.sqlite', 'test_v2');
```

or delete the cached database.

Answer (score 1):

What is the current path when you open the database?  `../` refers to the parent folder; are you absolutely certain that is the same folder where you’ve been creating a database using SQLite Manager?  SQLite doesn’t error out if you open a non-existing database; it’ll just create a new, empty, one.

Use a full, absolute path, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

## **You don't need to rename your database.**

You can try to delete the app in your simulator or emulator and install the app again. It worked for me. Since the app still has the old database. Re-installing the app with the new data (i.e. columns, rows). I use SQLite Manager plugin in Firefox as well.